# Export an images to pdf using display tag in jsp

Tags: jsp, displaytag

On my jsp there is data which contains questions and some images as graph analysis on feedback of questions.
When I try to export it using *display tag to pdf* I can successfully create a pdf mentioning the questions but in case of images I get a url of the images.

How can I export an image to pdf?

Here is my jsp code:

```
 <display:table id="data" name="${questions}" requestURI="" pagesize="10" export="true" >
      <display:column property="label" title="Question" sortable="true"/>
      <display:column title="Graph Analysis" media="">
         <img src="${imagePath}${reportData.clientName}/${data.label}.png"/>  
      </display:column>
      <display:setProperty name="export.pdf" value="true" />
 </display:table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this, but try adding another column with the media attribute set to pdf and have the column's property be the image blob or clob.

```
 <display:table id="data" name="${questions}" requestURI="" pagesize="10" export="true" >
      <display:column property="label" title="Question" sortable="true"/>
      <display:column title="Graph Analysis" media="">
         <img src="${imagePath}${reportData.clientName}/${data.label}.png"/>  
      </display:column>
      <display:column property="imageBlob" title="Photo/Image" media="pdf"/>
      <display:setProperty name="export.pdf" value="true" />
 </display:table>
```